# Istio envoy proxy consume pod' ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubernetes, istio

i'm testing istio(v1.4.6) with simple spring boot app (just return "OK"). (k8s server version: v1.15.10, client version: v1.14.8)

During the load test, the following error occurred and it was confirmed that the pod was abnormally terminated.

```
Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers 256M.
```

256M is my pod resource limitation.

i know ephemeral local storage is used for caching, stdout etc. so i set the envoy-proxy proxyLogLevel argument to 'info' from 'trace' and tested again. no error occurred.

I don't think changing simple settings like resource limitation or proxyLogLevel is a fundamental solution.

my question is below.

1. Does istio-proxy accumulate ephemeral local stroage without restrictions? or certain size?
2. Doesn't this storage used by istio-proxy flush?
3. How is ephemeral local storage used inside istio-proxy in detail?

Comment: As far as I checked [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/performance-and-scalability/#performance-summary-for-istio-hahahugoshortcode-s0-hbhb), `the Envoy proxy uses 0.5 vCPU and 50 MB memory per 1000 requests per second going through the proxy.` So maybe it was because of the huge amount of requests? I would check what happen if you change proxy resources limit, it should be possible with proxyMemoryLimit as mentioned [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/annotations/), if that won´t work I would just change the pod memory limit to higher value.

Comment: it think my issue is not related to memory or cpu. i tested additional two testcase, 1) set the ephemeral stroage of pod into 1Gi or 2) "kubectl edit istio-sidecar-injector configMap" and modify resource limit "ephemeral-storage".
both case 1), 2) have no error in same traffic (traffic amount: 300~400 TPS)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean increase ephemeral storage to higher value. I checked in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits) and it´s written here, `if the node where a Pod is running has enough of a resource available, it's possible (and allowed) for a container to use more resource than its request for that resource specifies. However, a container is not allowed to use more than its resource limit.` So as far as I understand increasing the ephemeral storage to higher value is the answer for your issue.